# An array problem in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

To access the array indice at the xth position we can use some sort of illustration as shown below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float i[20];
    for(int j=0;j<=20;j++)
        i[j]=0;
}
```

However the following piece of code does not work

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

float oldrand[55];
int jrand;

void advance_random(){
    int j1;
        float new_random;

    for(j1=0;j1<=23;j1++){
        int temp = j1+30;
        new_random = (oldrand[j1]) - (oldrand[temp]);
        if(new_random <0.0)
            new_random = new_random+1;
        oldrand[j1] = new_random;
    }
    for(j1=24;j1<=54;j1++){
        new_random[j1] = oldrand[j1] - oldrand[j1-23];
        if(new_random[j1]<0.0)
            new_random[j1] = new_random + 1;
        oldrand[j1]=new_random;
    }
}
```

I recieve the following error

```
ga.cpp:20: error: invalid types ‘float[int]’ for array subscript
ga.cpp:21: error: invalid types ‘float[int]’ for array subscript
ga.cpp:22: error: invalid types ‘float[int]’ for array subscript
```

I am not able to find a mistake in my code please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new_random` isn't declared as an array of floats, it's declared as a float. The compiler is trying to tell you you can't index into a float.

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, `new_random` is not declared as an array, hence the compiler error.

Moreover, with this type of loop

```
float i[20];
for(int j=0;j<=20;j++)
    i[j]=0;
```

you are going to run out of the array bounds and get undefined behaviour. Proper form is

```
for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
```

This is because in C/C++, arrays are indexed from 0, thus an array of 20 elements contains elements indexed from 0 to 19.

Answer (score 0):

oldRand is an array new_random is just a float so

```
new_random[j1]
```

is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You declared new_random as a float, not an array of floats, and are trying to use the array method of accessing it (new_random[j1]).

Answer (score 0):

This part of your first snippet is wrong:

```
int main(){
    float i[20];
    for(int j=0;j<=20;j++)
        i[j]=0;
}
```

The last iteration of that loop will assign to `i[20]` which does not exist (because `float i[20]` defines an array of floats from `i[0]` to `i[19]`). The right way is:

```
int main(){
    float i[20];
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        i[j]=0;
}
```

Note that `j<20` and not `j<=20`

Comment: Technically it does exist, it just isn't what he thinks it is.

Comment: @Blindy: No, technically it doesn't exist. There are no semantics that define what that pseudo-element would be.

Comment: @Tomalek, unless you're right at the edge of the 32-bit (or 64-bit) address range, `i+20` will *always* exist.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are treating the variable `new_random` as an array when you have declared it as a normal float.

Comment: Wow.. Seems the "this question has a new answer" banner didn't work this time :)

Answer (score 0):

new_random is not an array.  You are trying to treat it as one in the following lines:

```
new_random[j1] = oldrand[j1] - oldrand[j1-23];
        if(new_random[j1]<0.0)
            new_random[j1] = new_random + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the lines causing the problem:

```
for(j1=24;j1<=54;j1++){ 
    new_random[j1] = oldrand[j1] - oldrand[j1-23]; 
    if(new_random[j1]<0.0) 
        new_random[j1] = new_random + 1; 
    oldrand[j1]=new_random; 
}
```

As has been said, the "new_random**[j1]**" is illegal - it should work correctly as soon as you remove the "[j1]":

```
for(j1=24;j1<=54;j1++){ 
    new_random = oldrand[j1] - oldrand[j1-23]; 
    if(new_random<0.0) 
        new_random = new_random + 1; 
    oldrand[j1]=new_random; 
}
```